# How to create a new table given X and Y from a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a new dataset where it can take two columns and make a new table based on a calculation of a third column.

```
Cust    T       S1      S2      S3      S4
1009    150     1007    1006    1001    1000
1010    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
1011    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
1013    10000   1007    1006    1001    1000
1931    60      1008    1007    1006    1005
1141    1000    1014    1013    1007    1006
```

I need to make a new table where it is:

```
Cust    1014   1013    1008    1007     1006       1001       1000
1009    NA     NA      NA      T *.1    T *.1      T*.05      T * .025
1010    NA     NA      NA      T *.1    T *.1      T*.05      T * .025
1011    NA     NA      NA      T *.1    T *.1      T*.05      T * .025
1013    NA     NA      NA      T *.1    T *.1      T*.05      T * .025
1931    NA     NA      T*.1    T *.1    T*.05      T * .025   NA
1141    T*.1    T *.1  NA      T*.05    T * .025   NA         NA
```

I just can't seem to figure it out and I'm not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: What does T*.1 mean exactly? In short what logic is being used to do the transformations?

Comment: It is an equation, it stands for Total. It is a numeric value. Ideally if T = 150, T*.1 would return 15.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% gather(key=k,value = val, -c('Cust','T')) %>%
       mutate(val_upd=ifelse(k=='S1'|k=='S2','T*.1',ifelse(k=='S3','T*.05','T*.025'))) %>% 
       #Change 'T*.1' to T*.1 to get the actual value
       select(-T,-k) %>% dcast(Cust~val,value.var='val_upd')


  Cust   1000  1001   1005   1006  1007 1008 1013 1014
1 1009 T*.025 T*.05   <NA>   T*.1  T*.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 1010 T*.025 T*.05   <NA>   T*.1  T*.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 1011 T*.025 T*.05   <NA>   T*.1  T*.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 1013 T*.025 T*.05   <NA>   T*.1  T*.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
5 1141   <NA>  <NA>   <NA> T*.025 T*.05 <NA> T*.1 T*.1
6 1931   <NA>  <NA> T*.025  T*.05  T*.1 T*.1 <NA> <NA>
```

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Cust    T       S1      S2      S3      S4
1009    150     1007    1006    1001    1000
1010    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
1011    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
1013    10000   1007    1006    1001    1000
1931    60      1008    1007    1006    1005
1141    1000    1014    1013    1007    1006
", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, the only issue is that it isn't returning values for the cells.

Comment: @TimothyH see my comment below `mutate`. If you need your final output as a dataframe; try `.... %>% as.data.frame() -> new.df`

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather(select = -c(Cust, T)) %>%
       select(-key) %>%
       spread(value, T) %>%
       map2_dfc(c(1, .025, .05, rep(.1, 6)), ~ .x * .y)

#    Cust `1000` `1001` `1005` `1006` `1007` `1008` `1013` `1014`
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1009   3.75    7.5     NA     15     15     NA     NA     NA
# 2  1010   1.25    2.5     NA      5      5     NA     NA     NA
# 3  1011   1.25    2.5     NA      5      5     NA     NA     NA
# 4  1013 250     500       NA   1000   1000     NA     NA     NA
# 5  1141  NA      NA       NA    100    100     NA    100    100
# 6  1931  NA      NA        6      6      6      6     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using a combination of `reshape2::melt`, `dplyr::select`, `tidyr::spread` and `dplyr::mutate`. May not be the best way, but it should do what you want:

```
# Read the data (if you don't already have it loaded)
df <- read.table(text="Cust    T       S1      S2      S3      S4
                       1009    150     1007    1006    1001    1000
                       1010    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
                       1011    50      1007    1006    1001    1000
                       1013    10000   1007    1006    1001    1000", header=T)

# Manipulate your data.frame. Replace df with the name of your data.frame
reshape2::melt(df, c("Cust", "T"), c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-variable) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(value, T) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(`1007`=`1007`*0.1,
         `1006`=`1006`*0.1,
         `1001`=`1001`*0.05,
         `1000`=`1000`*0.025)

#  Cust   1000  1001 1006 1007
#1 1009   3.75   7.5   15   15
#2 1010   1.25   2.5    5    5
#3 1011   1.25   2.5    5    5
#4 1013 250.00 500.0 1000 1000
```

You'll need the backticks as R doesn't handle having numeric colnames very well.

Let me know if I've misunderstood anything/something doesn't make sense

Comment: If there are thousands of rows, is there a way to read.table the data frame? Sorry, I'm super new to R.

Comment: That is just for other users. If you already have the dataframe no need to read it. you just need to replace my `df` with your dataframe name in the second bit of code

Comment: But in future, `read.csv`, `read.table` will work if you have your data in a csv or .txt file format

Comment: Why not use `tidyr` `gather` as `melt` is deprecated?!

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance! So it does work if I am consistently using the same values for S1:S4. However, ideally, it should be about 1000 worth of columns with only 4 variables being filled in. I'm sorry if I'm not clear!